# Where disk read-only attribute is stored on Windows?

Tags: windows, diskpart, disk-management

When you set read only attribute on disk or partition with diskpart, is it stored on the disk itself? Some answers here say yes but in my experience it is not saved on the disk. I marked removable USB disk read only on one machine (win 8.1), brought it to other machine (win10) and diskpart does not show it as read only. 
Is there an option to save this attribute on the disk?

Comment: Why are you actually trying to do this? As the disk is still writeable any system could remove the write protection. Was that stick still write protected after you attached it to the Win 8.1 machine again? If no you would know it's not even a persistent flag. What steps did you take to set the flag?

Comment: @Seth I do this because I don't normally work from an admin account. So it should be a bit harder for bad guys to mess with my disk )) Also, I'm asking, if there is an option to YES make it  persistent on the disk. The steps are usual: run diskpart as elevated admin and do 'set attrib disk readonly'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer:

`Attributes  DISK  [set | clear] READONLY` stores the attribute **in the Windows registry**, not on the physical disk. This means **it is only valid for the currently running Windows installation and it won't be carried, set and enforced on other OSes**.

`Attributes VOLUME [set | clear] READONLY` stores the attribute **on the physical disk**. This means **it WILL be carried, set and enforced also onto other OSes, including Linux** (I had to manually remount the disk in rw mode, plus it didn't touched the stored attribute, so I had to manually remove it in Windows).

**BE CAREFUL with administrative access, though**:
while the `DISK` attribute prevents **ALL writes on the entire disk** (i.e. both the volume(s) filesystem and the partition table), the `VOLUME` attribute prevents writing **ONLY to the volume(s) filesystem**, leaving the partition table STILL writable (i.e. you can still delete a read-only volume).

---

## Long answer:

### Attributes `DISK` [set | clear] READONLY

The attribute is stored in the value named `"Attribute"`, located at the registry subkey `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\*\Disk*\Device Parameters\Partmgr`, where `*` is the disk's enumerated and installed device node (look in Device Properties in Disk Management).

It's a bitmask value, and the `readonly` attribute is Bit #1 (Bit #0 is for online/offline disk status), so setting `readonly` on an online disk will change the value from `0` to `2`, but setting it on an offline disk will change the value from `1` to `3`.

**Advantages:**
The disk is **entirely** read-only: all write attempts will guarantee to **FAIL**, **including its partition table** (e.g. deleting/creating volumes, changing the Unique Disk Signature/ID and so on), plus the status will be clearly visible in Disk Management.

**Disadvantages:**
It is valid only for the currently running Windows installation until its enumeration device node stays the same (no guarantee for removable drives). The disk will be in read-write mode again if it is connected to another computer or its device node changes for any reason, e.g. it is connected to another bus, port or hub (especially USB) or it is uninstalled and reinstalled in Device Manager.

### Attributes `VOLUME` [set | clear] READONLY

The attribute is **physically stored on disk**, depending by its partition style (MBR or GPT).

**On `GPT` disks:**
The attribute is stored in the `Attributes` field of the volume's partition table entry, and **it is valid ONLY for that volume** (as declared in the `diskpart` help description).

**On `MBR` disks:**
The attribute is stored at **offset 0x400h** (or sector #2 on a 512-byte logically formatted disk) as a "short version" of a GPT entry where only the `Type GUID` and `Attributes` field are used for a total of 0x18h bytes, and it is valid **FOR ALL VOLUMES** (as declared in the `diskpart` help description).

Here below a sample hexadecimal output and its structure:

```
   Hex Offset    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F
   0000000400   A2 A0 D0 EB E5 B9 33 44 87 C0 68 B6 B7 26 99 C7
   0000000410   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10
```

- 0x400: 128-bit GUID `Type GUID`, with value `EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7` (i.e. the Microsoft *Basic Data Partition* Type GUID);
- 0x410: 64-bit integer `Attributes`, with value `0x1000000000000000` (i.e. bit `#60` set).

In the same way, it is also possible to set the `SHADOWCOPY`, `HIDDEN` and `NODEFAULTDRIVELETTER` attributes (bits `#61`, `#62` and `#63`, respectively).

**Advantages:**
The attribute is **preserved** when the disk is connected to other systems, e.g. Linux, which preserves it even if the volume is (re)mounted in rw mode.

**Disadvantages:**
The attribute is not visible in Disk Management but only within `diskpart`, plus:

On `GPT` disks:

- attributes applies ONLY to the selected volume (but this is expected behavior);
- it does not prevent the read-only volume to be deleted (but if it is deleted, the attribute is automatically cleared, because its associated GPT entry is entirely zeroed out).

On `MBR` disks:

- attributes applies to ALL volumes on the disk, due to no other way to set attributes on MBR (and the consequent on-disk attribute structure);
- volumes can be still deleted (for unknown reason, AFAIK);
- the attribute is NOT cleared if one or more or all volumes are deleted (the only way to safely clear it is by executing `attributes VOLUME CLEAR readonly` at the `diskpart` prompt);
- new volumes can still be created, but cannot be formatted (because it is a write operation).

---

This is my simple point of view, but the reason why the volume attributes are applied to ALL VOLUMES on MBR disks can be:

1. No more available places in the MBR sector, 'cause "Boot Indicator" flag refuses any value other 0x80 or 0x00 (or the boot sequence will go crazy) and the "Optional" bytes located at offset 0x1BC (444) are declared as "reserved" (despite some bits of that 16-bit field could be used);
2. Windows shares the same Type GUID for all filesystems in a partition, so setting that Type GUID it means "for all data volumes" (other Type GUIDs like the Recovery partition will not receive a Diskpart "volume" entry, only a "partition" one).

Comment: Thank you ST83, this is what I wanted to know. The details about volume attributes are interesting.

Comment: @ddbug You're welcome! I was also trying to get over it just like you, until I've managed to find it when I've update the hex editor window with the freshly created VHD with Disk Management console (and executing the `attribute VOLUME set readonly` command).

Answer (score 0):

This information can't be stored on the partition - it is probably an attribute associated with the filesystem - its not uncommon for filesystems to have such an attribute to force a diskcheck before allowing further changes to be made to the disk if the filesystem is not in a consistent state at shutdown.

Comment: So it should be in the registry. In the cache of mount points info,HKLM\SYSTEM\MountedDevices , I cannot see it.

Answer (score 0):

The Read-Only flag cannot be stored on disk itself.
To get the disk read-only status, you may use the PowerShell command Get-Disk.
For instance: (Get-Disk -Number 2).IsReadOnly